# create a table and populate it on a popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML file. I wanna dynamically create a table, populate it on a popup window. The table data will come from a local database. Can someone give me an idea how to approach this? I'm new to javascript, so any help is much appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Are you open to use Javascript libraries like jQuery?

Comment: this will help you: http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/

Answer (score 1):

If you have jQuery and Bootstrap available for use, then this would be a great example where both libraries can work together to help you.

If so,

Requesting your data via Ajax will be your best bet.  Look into the jQuery $.post() method.  Internally the jQuery ajax implementation has over 800 lines of code to get it cross browser complaint.  I'd recommend utilizing the work of other developers, opposed to writing the ajax implementation without jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Once you have your data, you can populate it into a table with a View template or JavaScript.

If you have Bootstrap, a css "framework", you can use this to really give your tables a neat appearance. Assign your table element the class "table" and "table-striped", this will give your tables a neat and clean appearance.  Here is the documentation for Bootstrap,

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

As far as a pop up window, the modal window offered by bootstrap is a very easy implementation of a user friendly pop up window.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

If you don't have these tools, then I would suggest using them or starting a campaign to get them used.  They're cross browser complaint and can save A LOT of time.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You might also find Knockout.JS http://knockoutjs.com/ useful in conjunction with previous answers suggestion to aid populating and manipulating the data in your table once you've fetched it via jQuery's AJAX.